# Is there a way to split input into 4 int and pass onto a method (int a, int b, int c, int d) in java?

Tags: java

I have this problem.
Suppose I want to take user input starting from the first line of input as integer that will determine the number of inputs, and the inputs must be a numbers of 4 categories (day , hr, min, sec). As an example of input

Input:

Enter integer: 3

4 5 6 3555

6 11 3 120

1 0 44 11

Now what I want to do with these inputs is store them and seperate each line containing the 4 numbers (then seperate the 4 numbers) and then I want to pass each line into a method that accepts 4  parameters.

Is it possible? And how to code it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please see: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273) (don't just change your question to "How").
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use BufferedReader with InputStreamReader and read each line as `String` and wrap it using Wrapper class to int for converting String to int we use this method `Integer.parseInt(<String yourString>)`

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
int totalLines = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
for(int i = 0; i < totalLines ; i++){
   String [] num = br.readLine().split(" ");
   int num1 = Integer.parseInt(num[0]);
   int num2 = Integer.parseInt(num[1]);
   int num3 = Integer.parseInt(num[2]);
   int num4 = Integer.parseInt(num[3]);
  // here call the method you want to call
}
```

`.split(" ")` will split the line on the base of the parameter we define in it, in your case it was `space` and remember split returns a String array